# Why is the exponent part of floating number so complicated?

Tags: floating-point, double, ieee-754

I'm studying now how floating number is implemented in modern computers.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format

I understand that a floating number is represented via three components: sign, exponent, and fraction.

The sign part is super easy since that represents whether the number is positive or negative using one bit.
If 8 bits are assigned to the exponent part, why the interpretation would be 2^{x - 127} rather than simple 2^{x}?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the fastest way to compare both positive and negative exponents.

You have more information [here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponent_bias).

Comment: Oh, that's for efficiency!! Thank you very much!

Comment: The reasoning in that Wikipedia article is dubious and does not cite any sources for its claims about the motivation for using a bias. (The sole reference cited is for specifying what value the bias has.) It says the values are “ordered properly” whether the bits are interpreted as floating-point or integer, but this is false: Consider as integers, the negative floating-point numbers are in reverse order. And using a bias instead of two’s complement for the exponent confers little or no advantage to speed; the latter would require only reversing the sense of one bit, which has little cost.

Comment: Furthermore, speeding comparison is not a great motivation as the most common operations on floating-point numbers are arithmetic operations, not comparison. The format ought to be optimized primarily to support arithmetic, rather than comparison.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: Biased exponents do make it possible to implement `nextafter` with an integer increment or decrement of the bit pattern (according to sign of the input and desired direction of change).  Also, software floating point being able to use integer compares of the whole bit pattern after handling the sign seems good, instead of also breaking out mantissa / exponent.